# Questions about NHibernate listeners

Tags: nhibernate

I found some information about NHb listeners online like this documentation:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/package-summary.html, but it's not definitely enough to understand in details how they work. This are questions regarding let's say `PostUpdateEventListener` I was unable to find answers for:

1) Does not it really run when we call `Session.Save(entity)` with no changes done to entity, I mean when no SQL Update script runs on database? If it does, is there any Nhb event/listener to track actual database update, with `UPDATE` statement running on db only? Our entity is configured with `DynamicUpdate()` if it makes any difference.

2) What if we have separate nested entity like [Name] (not component, stored to separate table) or list of entities, which our listened entity like [Person] references to. Now we update person's name without doing any changes to [Person] entity properties. Will `PostUpdateEventListener` be invoked for [Person] if we run `Session.Save(person)`, or it runs just once for [Name]?

Maybe somebody could give me a link to a clear well-described online documentation explaining listeners in good details and answering questions like this. Thanks

Comment: http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener   http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/changing-values-in-nhibernate-events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out in practice, and just for the sake of posterity here are answers:

1) `PostUpdateEventListener` does not really run as long as no actual changes are made to database, even if you run `Flush` explicitly

2) `PostUpdateEventListener` runs for `[Name]` only, in case it's an entity. If `[Name]` is a component, PostUpdateEventListener runs `for @event.Entity is [Person]` obviously.